# Some weird exception throws

Tags: c++

The strange problem appears in my program. It is working, but in debugging it shows the "Exception thrown" in random places at the outputting

```
cout<<"Average value:"<<u3.apr();
    _getch();
```

Sometimes, it even throws this error after the main function (Behind the {})
It is quite annoying because the program just closes after 3 seconds because of these errors.
(Maybe that's because of class, but I'm trying to learn it ;) )

Have tried already changing lines order, rewriting class name and array name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class vid
{
private:
    int i, j;
    double rez, sum=0;
public:
    int size;
    double *arr = new double[size];

    double apr()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            sum += (*(arr + i));
        }

        return sum / size;

    }
};
int main()
{
    vid u3;
    cout << "Enter array length:";
    cin >> u3.size;
    for (int i = 0; i < u3.size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter array's " << i << " element:" << endl;
        cin >> *(u3.arr+i);
    }
    cout << "Your array:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < u3.size; i++)
    {
        cout << *(u3.arr + i) << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout<<"Average value:"<<u3.apr();
    _getch();
}
```

Thanks for any help ;)

Comment: `double *arr = new double[size];` what value is size when this is executed? The answer is it is a garbage value because it was not initialized. And you can't initialize it after the fact. `arr` was already allocated.

Comment: Testing your code with [different compilers](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NMRfe-) would warn you about this and make it much more trivial to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u3.size is not set until after u3 is constructed.  By setting u3.size you can avoid this compiler-time error.

It seems that as an alternative solution, you might want to consider how to get rid of the `new` call and the need to write a destructor that will delete arr.

By creating a constructor that takes a size parameter AND by switching arr to a std::vector, you can allow the class to hold the vector and handle memory allocation and deallocation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class vid
{
private:
    int i, j;
    double rez, sum=0;

public:
    int size;
    std::vector<double> arr;

    // constructor requires size to be passed in;
    // constructor initializes the arr array with the passed in size to zeroes.
    vid(int argSize) : size(argSize), arr(argSize, 0.0){ }

    double apr()
    {
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
        sum += arr[i];
      }
      return sum / size;
    }
};
int main()
{
  uint size;
  cout << "Enter array length:";
  cin >> size;

  vid u3(size);

  for (int i = 0; i < u3.size; i++)
  {
    cout << "Enter array's #" << i << " element:" << endl;
    cin >> u3.arr[i];
  }
  cout << "Your array:" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < u3.size; i++)
  {
    cout << u3.arr[i] << "\t";
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout<<"Average value:"<<u3.apr();
  char ch;
  cin >> ch;
}
```

Comment: @drescherjm:  you are correct.  I implemented as you see it because as I first wrote the code, i was trying to leave OP's main function untouched, which required a preallocation of the elements of the vector.  It was not sufficient to use `reserve()`. 
 However, if you use push_back in main(), there is no need to preallocate the actual elements.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about the initialization point. I have deleted the comment.

Comment: @drescherjm:  Thanks.  It took me way too long to get my code to compile, trying to pre-initialize it as a private member.  Later, I made it public to match the main() code, but of course, in a production implementation, arr would have been private.

Answer (score 5):

`arr` is initialised when `u3` is constructed.

But you didn't populate `u3.size` until later.

So, your array has indeterminate length (which is already UB), and your accesses later may be invalid.

You're going to have to manage your class's member a bit more cleverly!

Such classes generally have a "resize" function that performs the allocation per the requested size. Don't forget to safely kill any prior allocation, transplanting data if necessary. You can find online plenty of examples of a vector implementation.

Certainly renaming classes and randomly re-ordering the lines of your program's source code is not going to solve anything.